# how to pass in the function tags from other node

Tags: javascript, html

I have product:

```
<article>
        <img src="https://static.svyaznoy.ru/upload/iblock/d1c/4165313_10.jpg/resize/483x483/hq/" id="Phone1" alt="image" title="nokia">
        <h2>100$</h2>
        <p>Nokia</p>

        <span class="btns">
           <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn1" id="Phone1"   onclick="addItem()">Addу</a>
           <a href="" class="btn1">about</a></span>

    </article>
function addItem(id){
    console.log(id);
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('POST', '/addItem', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({id:id}));
    }
```

How to send in the function addItem() - img src, content in h2 tag and content in p tag, if href does not see them?

Comment: What do you actually try to achieve? And what is your current javascript?

Comment: i try send this info in my express server for add in db. My func:
function addItem(id){
        console.log(id);
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open('POST', '/addItem', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify({id:id}));
        }

Comment: Please show the `addItem()` function so we can understand what it is expecting to be passed.

Comment: It is not recommended to send the product data directly from the HTML to your database.. A better way would be to send the current database ID of the product.

Comment: `addItem(document.querySelector('img').getAttribute('src'),document.querySelector('h2').innerText)`.

Comment: But if src more then 1 and i need specific img or h2?

Comment: @Vlad See my answer below. Each "Add" button will target the appropriate product without any code changes.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have two elements with `id=Phone`. `id`'s must be unique.

You'll need to query for the elements that have the content you want and you can do that with **[`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)**.

Then, you can extract the data from the elements. To get the `src` value, just access the `.src` property of the image element. To get the contents of the `p` and `h2`, use the `.textContent` properties.

Finally, you'll need to pass the data to your function by sending the parent `article` element as a single argument to `addItem`. This will allow `addItem` to use that single DOM element as a starting point for extracting the data it requires.

Also, you should address the following:

- You should not be using inline HTML event attributes (`onclick`) to
  set up your events. That technique is 20+ years old **[and there are
  many reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991)**. Instead, follow modern standards
  and separate your JavaScript from your HTML and use
  **[`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)** to set up event handlers.
- Don't use a hyperlink just to trigger some JavaScript.
  Hyperlinks are for navigation. If you just want to give the user
  something to click on, just about any HTML element supports a `click`
  event. By following this advice, you'll notice that you don't have to
  worry about disabling the native click behavior of the link with
  `javascript:void(0)`, which is also an old, antiquated technique that
  shouldn't be used.

```js
let btn = document.getElementById("add");
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  // Get a reference to the <article> parent element and pass that.
  // This way, addItem can extract any/all data from that structure 
  // that it may need.
  let art = this.parentElement.parentElement;
  addItem(art);
});

function addItem(article){
    // Scan the article element for the descedants that are desired
    // and then get the content of those and use them to create a new object
    let product = {
      id:article.querySelector("h2").textContent, 
      src:article.querySelector("img").src, 
      brand:article.querySelector("p").textContent
    };
    
    console.log(product);
    
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/addItem', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(product));
}
```

```css
/* You can use many different elements and make them look/feel like buttons */
.btn1 { cursor:pointer; display:inline-block; padding:3px; border:1px solid lightgrey; }
.btn1:hover { background-color:#e0e0e0; }

img {height:50px;} /* Just for this example */
```

```html
<article>
  <img src="https://static.svyaznoy.ru/upload/iblock/d1c/4165313_10.jpg/resize/483x483/hq/" 
       id="Phone1" alt="image" title="nokia">
  <h2>100$</h2>
  <p>Nokia</p>

  <span class="btns">
    <span class="btn1" id="add">Addу</span>  
    <span class="btn1">About</span>
  </span>
</article>
```